# How to get all records in Postgres were a list in json contain an element?

Tags: postgresql

I need to get all elements from Postgres table where a value is in the **list** containing in JSONs in the column `ids`.

```
col1 | ids
-----+-----
 123 |  {"ids": ["743d83f4-4181-43a1-9568-5da2ce198833", "9dcc1bb3-142a-4b3d-b4e6-bfc622418e9a"]}
 456 |  {"ids": ["9dcc1bb3-142a-4b3d-b4e6-bfc622418e9a"]}
```

Comment: You say "any of lists", but each of your example JSON only contains a single list.  Please provide better example data.

Comment: sorry, where a value is in the list. Edited

Answer (score 1):

This is a containment operation, so use @>

```
WHERE ids @> '{"ids":["9dcc1bb3-142a-4b3d-b4e6-bfc622418e9a"]}'
```